# Tradução de palavras Regex para facilitar nas Respostas

Tags: debate

> Aos usuários que utilizam a tag
> [[regex]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex)

Um dos sites mais utilizados para a criação de demos Regex é o [Regex101](https://regex101.com/). Por possuir uma explicação e cores de formatação simples, didáticas e intuitivas.

Portanto, achei válido contribuir na [tradução para o pt](http://r101.cf/), pois isto facilitaria na criação de respostas no SOpt. Pois há explicação da Regex já criada automaticamente e guia de referência também. Facilitando a vida de alguns usuários.

Uma lista de referências se estende à toda linguagem Regex, portanto pode ser utilizada para traduzir qualquer site ou ajudar nos estudos de Expressões Regulares.

#### Tradução

A dúvida está na tradução de palavras técnicas, vocês pensam que as seguintes traduções estão corretas? E algumas palavras não possuem tradução, pois é melhor estar em inglês?

```
 ============================= ================================================= 
       match information                 informação de correspondência           
 ============================= ================================================= 
  match                         corresponder                                     
  lookahead                     ?                                                
  lookbehind                    ?                                                
  character                     caractere                                        
  range                         intervalo                                        
  greedy                        ganancioso?                                      
  lazy                          preguiçoso?                                      
  Unicode                       ?                                                
  Assert                        Assertar/Afirmar?                                
  as many times as possible     quantas vezes for possível                       
  giving back as needed         retornando quando necessário? (está estranho)    
  Non-capturing group           grupo de não captura                             
  escape sequences              sequência de escape                              
  quantifier                    quantificação(wiki)/quantificador(microsoft)     
  sticky                        ?                                                
  flags                         bandeiras                                        
  carriage return /r            fim de linha                                     
  case sensitive                sensível a maiúscula                             
  tab /t                        tabulação                                        
  newline /n                    nova linha                                       
  non-whitespace                espaço não em branco?                            
  backspace                     ?                                                
  capture everything enclosed   captura tudo incluso                             
  construct                     construtor                                       
  underscore/underline          ?                                                
  nth                           enésimo                                          
  form-feed /f                  ?                                                
  token                         ?                                                
  meta sequences                metassequências                                  
  anchors                       âncoras                                          
  character classes             classes de caracteres                            
  modifiers                     modificadores                                    
  global                        global                                           
  multi line                    multilinha                                       
  insensitive                   insensível                                       
  extended                      extendido                                        
  subpattern                    subpadrão                                        
  single line                   linha única                                      
 ============================= =================================================
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>match information</th><th>informação de correspondência</th></tr><tr><td>match</td><td>corresponder</td></tr><tr><td>lookahead</td><td>?</td></tr><tr><td>lookbehind</td><td>?</td></tr><tr><td>character</td><td>caractere</td></tr><tr><td>range</td><td>intervalo</td></tr><tr><td>greedy</td><td>ganancioso?</td></tr><tr><td>lazy</td><td>preguiçoso?</td></tr><tr><td>Unicode</td><td>?</td></tr><tr><td>Assert</td><td>Assertar/Afirmar?</td></tr><tr><td>as many times as possible</td><td>quantas vezes for possível</td></tr><tr><td>giving back as needed</td><td>retornando quando necessário? (está estranho)  </td></tr><tr><td>Non-capturing group</td><td>grupo de não captura</td></tr><tr><td>escape sequences</td><td>sequência de escape</td></tr><tr><td>quantifier</td><td>quantificação(wiki)/quantificador(microsoft)</td></tr><tr><td>sticky</td><td>?</td></tr><tr><td>flags</td><td>bandeiras</td></tr><tr><td>carriage return /r</td><td>fim de linha</td></tr><tr><td>case sensitive</td><td>sensível a maiúscula</td></tr><tr><td>tab /t</td><td>tabulação</td></tr><tr><td>newline /n</td><td>nova linha</td></tr><tr><td>non-whitespace</td><td>espaço não em branco?</td></tr><tr><td>backspace</td><td>?</td></tr><tr><td>capture everything enclosed</td><td>captura tudo incluso</td></tr><tr><td>construct</td><td>construtor</td></tr><tr><td>underscore/underline</td><td>?</td></tr><tr><td>nth</td><td>enésimo</td></tr><tr><td>form-feed /f</td><td>?</td></tr><tr><td>token</td><td>?</td></tr><tr><td>meta sequences</td><td>metassequências</td></tr><tr><td>anchors</td><td>âncoras</td></tr><tr><td>character classes</td><td>classes de caracteres</td></tr><tr><td>modifiers</td><td>modificadores</td></tr><tr><td>global</td><td>global</td></tr><tr><td>multi line</td><td>multilinha</td></tr><tr><td>insensitive</td><td>insensível</td></tr><tr><td>extended</td><td>extendido</td></tr><tr><td>subpattern</td><td>subpadrão</td></tr><tr><td>single line</td><td>linha única</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

[Ferramenta ASCII Table Format para criar a tabela](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

#### Documentos de Referência

Algumas referências para tradução:

[Linguagem de expressões regulares - referência rápida](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#atomic_zerowidth_assertions)

[Wiki - Expressão Regular](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular#Sintaxe)

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

[w3big](http://www.w3big.com/pt/python/python-reg-expressions.html)

#### Contribuição

Mais pessoas podem contribuir traduzindo ou revisando.

Outras palavras que eu possa ter esquecido podem ser adicionadas para ajudar.

#### Objetivo do Debate

Debater sobre as traduções de Expressões Regulares

Comment: "Unicode" seria o [padrão Unicode](https://unicode.org/)? Se não me engano, este nome é um termo inventado para dar a ideia de um código único ([*unique, unified, universal encoding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#History)), e por isso acho que não tem tradução. E para "flags" eu usaria "opções", "modificadores" ou algo do tipo, pois nunca vi ninguém dizer "bandeiras" neste contexto (assumindo que são aquelas opções `i` para case insensitive, `g` para "global match", etc). De qualquer forma, tradução de termos técnicos em TI é bem complicado, parabéns pela iniciativa!

Comment: A ideia é otima, claro que acho que tradução poderia até ser dispensada, mas uma explicação de um a um dos termos já seria o suficiente, mas isso é gosto, de qualquer forma, mesmo da forma que esta isso ficaria legal na wiki da tag [tag:regex], assim quem clicar na tag poderia, para ser mais claro no link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info